# Unable to create requested service (Hibernate + JPA)

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to set connection to my postgresql database for create a SessionFactoty. But, when i trying to start my application i always got errors about "Unable to create requested service"
**Password, name and url are correct.**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/Hibernate</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">vfrae0v5</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

</session-factory>
```

Got this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] at util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your property to:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect" />
```

The error is pretty clear, you didn't specify the hibernate.dialect property

Comment: its not persist.xml file

Comment: Well I think you need to set it in the persistence xml, I edit my comment

Comment: @DaniilBaev even so, the error is telling you the correct name is `hibernate.dialect` not just `dialect` as you have it listed here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the dialect if the connection to the database is possible, but in your case it looks like you don't have a database listening on 127.0.0.1:5432